# How can you map the exceedance of a threshold into an activation function of a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, inequality

I am totally new to Artificial Neural Networks. Let’s say that the model you are trying to turn into an artificial neural network has an output that is triggered *only* by the exceedance of a threshold: $y\geq y_{1}. $Therefore, you need to find a way to use this inequality as an activation function. Is this feasible?

Comment: Elaborate a little bit more. All you talking about input data, that will only activate a `1` if the input data is above a certain value. Or are you talking about output: if the output is higher than a certain treshold, it will output `1`, else `0`.

Comment: Sorry to have not made this clear. The 1 will be produced in the output only if the input is already 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is feasable. This is also called a `Binary/Step` activation function. You must only use this activation function on the output neurons.

The `Step` function will round down an answer that is lower than 0.5 to `0`, and an answer that is higher than 0.5 to `1`. However, please note that you do not need to use a binary activation function to output 1 - I advise you to just use TanH or sigmoid and backpropagate a whole bunch of iterations.

However, in other comments, you mentioned that you know what `y1` is. *That is not of importance*, the network will act as a black box and will figure out a treshold itself. Don't set up your own activation function just to get the right output - that avoids the whole point of backpropagation.